# Payment from Apple for developer

Tags: ios, applications, ios-appstore

I'm an iOS developer and I've been selling very few apps on the App Store. I would like to ask some questions about withdrawn money from iTunes Connect.

---

**I already know**

- Minimum payment: $150 (USD)
- Apple will fund every month

---

**My question**

- If I earn over $150 in my account, for example: $500, how much money
  will I receive?
- I've known that Apple will fund every month, additionally, after 45
  days of the first day of the month, is that correct? I am a little
  bit confused to calculatate this, for example, I started sale of my app at July 16, 2015, so what day does money arrived to my bank account? In addition, how do I calculate this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> If I earn over $150 in my account, for example: $500, how much money
>   will I receive?

Depends on what you mean by "earn". There are two stats: "Sales" and "Proceeds". If your app receives $500 (sales), Apple will take its cut (like 33%) and you will earn like $335 (proceeds).

You can go to iTunes Connect, then Sales and Trends, and you will see the two stats there.

> I've known that Apple will fund every month, additionally, after 45 days of the first day of the month, is that correct?

If by "fund" you mean "send money to my bank account", this isn't always true. Apple will *normally* do it every month, but there are cases in which it will delay the payment for several months (this tends to happen if your proceeds exceed a certain threshold - I imagine its for security/verification reasons). So it is possible that Apple will retain the profit of 2 or more months and pay at another month.

And yes, I believe that the very first month of sales (or 45 days) is always delayed. So your first payment will usually correspond to the first two months of sales.

> I started sale of my app at July 16, 2015, so what day does money
>   arrived to my bank account?

Well, you will definitely not get anything on July. I suspect that you won't receive a payment in August either. You will probably receive your first payment on September (or late August), and from this point on, further payments will occur each month (normally).

> In addition, how do I calculate this?

Go to iTunes Connect. There is a section (I forgot how it is called, I think it is "financial" or "payments" something like that). You can observe here how much Apple **owes you** per month. This amount is what they are supposed to pay you.

Since you begun sales very recently, it is likely you won't find any data here yet.

---

Apple can be late with payments. It's normal. Simply keep track of the "amount owed" in iTunes Connect and you're pretty much guaranteed that the payment will be performed in a future.

Comment: Voted+ and Accepted
I'm sorry for my later vote, I was busy last week. I've just read your help, your answer not only what I need, it also more helpful than I can imagine. Thanks alot.

Answer (score 2):

Hope this helps you:

The amount will be deposited on same day that apple mention's as **next payment** date in you iTunes account one's your payable amount reaches more than 150$

**Payments and Amounts Owed:** from apple Document

The Payments and Amounts Owed section shows your last payment, the amount we owe you for the next month, and when to expect your next payment.
• Amounts Owed (Converted). This section includes our estimate of the amounts we owe you. What you see is your earnings, after we’ve applied any necessary taxes and adjustments.

The amounts are in the currency of your bank account, which we base on an estimated foreign exchange rate. The amount that we pay you is based on the actual foreign exchange rate on the day we pay you. These amounts don't include withholding taxes. If you want more detail, look on the Owed pane. 
 
Apple only show your next payment date if the amount we owe you is above the minimum payment amount during the most recent payment cycle. It’s also the date when your bank should receive payment.

[Please refer here for more details](https://itunesconnect.apple.com/docs/Apps_Payments_Finance_Reports_Guide.pdf)

Comment: Thanks Sujania because of helping me, but I still confusing a lot :(

Comment: Any clarification do you need?

Comment: When I read your answer, I've just known that the amount I receive depending on taxes and I should look at Owed pane. I think I going to wait some other answer and study cafully again apple document, anyway thanks for your help.

Comment: When you refer "payable amount" - it is about "Proceeds" right ? not Sales threshold .